# Win32 SETX command hangs sometimes

Tags: windows-xp

I am using the resource kit on WinXP and sometimes the SETX command hangs with simple variable assignments. Why is this and how can I avoid it?

e.g. setx x x

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it.

SetX that you may download from the Support Tools may hang on CERTAIN XP. Don't know why, but it appears to be bugged.

Please, use the Windows 2000 SetX command instead that you may [download here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/setx/1.00.0.1/nt5/en-us/setx_setup.exe) (direct link to .exe).

Answer (score 0):

This will only work on win7:
SETX /M TEMP C:\TEMP
(Will set a variable "/M" containing "TEMP" on WinXP)

This will work as expected on both winXP and Win7:
SETX -M TEMP C:\TEMP